# jquery popup image centering

Tags: jquery, html, css

ok so I have a site that has several thumbnails.  When I click a thumbnail I have an image that pops up centered horizontally and vertically on the page.  What I want is for image to pop up relative to the browser window but if I use position "fixed" it won't scroll if it overflows past the browser window.  Here is my code..

```
#popup_image {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 1400px;
z-index: 201;
display: none;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-image: url(images/fullgraphic3.jpg);
}

<div id="popup_image">
</div>
```

I would like it something like this.. [Spoon Graphics](http://www.spoongraphics.co.uk/portfolio.html)

No matter what thumbnail you click or how far down the page you are it is position relative to browser window but when you scroll the image doesn't scroll too.

Comment: From what you say, `overflow-y: auto;` should do the trick if you use `position: fixed;`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

```
function center(divid) {
    $(divid).css("position","absolute");
    $(divid).css("top", (($(window).height() - $(divid).outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    $(divid).css("left", (($(window).width() - $(divid).outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
}
```

Use method:

```
center("#divid");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can center divs like so:

**CSS**

```
.popup {
    background:#AAA;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    position:fixed;
    width:auto;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function PopUp(){
    $('.popup').each(function(){
        $(this).css('left',($(window).width()-$(this).outerWidth())/ 2 + 'px');
        $(this).css('top',($(window).height()-$(this).outerHeight())/ 2 + 'px');
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/qZatW/)