# How to center an image in a pop up window

Tags: javascript

My website opens a Window with a single image when a button is clicked.

I've got everything working other than the last bit - how do I center the image in the pop up?

I'm not asking how to center the new Window, just the content of the new window.

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = cont.getAttribute("data-img");
img.style.boxShadow = "1px 1px 3px #333;"

//as per https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/
img.style.position="absolute";
img.style.top= "50%";
img.style.left= "50%";
img.style.marginTop= Number((img.height/2) * - 1) + "px"; /* Half the height */
img.style.marginLeft= Number((img.width/2) * - 1) + "px"; /* Half the width */

showImage(img);
});

function showImage(imgEle) {  
   var w = imgEle.width + (10 / 100 * imgEle.width);
   var h = imgEle.height+ (10 / 100 * imgEle.height);
   var url=imgEle.getAttribute('src');
   window.open(url,"Image Viewer",'width='+w+',height='+h+',resizable=1, titlebar=no, toolbar=no');
}
```

The above works in that the new window shows and my image is the only thing in the page but the image is stuck in the top left and I'd like it centered.

I know there are issues with this approach (pop up blockers).

As per the tag of Javascript and the fact I'm clearly using only Javascript, I'm after a javascript solution (not reliant on any libraries/frameworks) please

Comment: Can you approve an answer?

Answer (score 0):

[jquery popup image centering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374311/jquery-popup-image-centering) from here

```
function center(divid) {
$(divid).css("position","absolute");
$(divid).css("top", (($(window).height() - $(divid).outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
$(divid).css("left", (($(window).width() - $(divid).outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
}
```

Use method:

```
center("#divid");
```

Comment: You're using Javascript, why can't you just use Jquery too then?

Comment: You've tagged it as a Javascript question, my answer is valid considering you haven't specified at all that you apparantly don't want answers in Jquery? Plus Jquery is a Javascript library, I don't see how Jquery answers don't have a place at a Javascript question if it's not specified the answer shouldn't be Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your styles

```
img.style.display = "block";
img.style.margin = "0 auto";
```

Comment: @Dave you're right, my bad.  Just fixed it. I was confused when I wrote it because I was using another piece of code I had that worked differently.

Answer (score 0):

Using what you already have:

```
       function showImage(imgEle) {  
          var url=imgEle.src;
          var w = imgEle.width + (10 / 100 * imgEle.width);
          var h = imgEle.height+ (10 / 100 * imgEle.height);
          imgEle.style.marginLeft = 50% - (w / 2);// Center horizontally
          imgEle.style.marginTop = 50% - (h / 2); // Center vertically
          imgEle.style.display = "block";
          window.open(url,"Image Viewer",'width='+w+',height='+h+',resizable=1, titlebar=no, toolbar=no');
        }
```

If for some reason that doesn't work,try using the [`transform` centering trick](https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/)

```
    // The modal that is the image's parent.
    // Absolute or fixed works as well.
    .box {
       position: relative;
    }

    // The image inside the modal.
    .center {
       position: absolute;
       left: 50%;
       top: 50%;
       transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We should *import* styled image element into the popup rather than load image resource in a popup.

```
function showImg (imgURL) {

  var imageElem = document.createElement('img');

  imageElem.onload = function () {

    // style this image element
    // ...

    // create popup window with certain dimensions
    // ...

    // import image element from current document into popup document body <<<<<<<<<
    popupWindow.document.body.appendChild(popupWindow.document.importNode(imageElem));
  };

  // load image now 
  imageElem.src = imgURL;
};
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ycw7788/my4ke7a3/)

Comment: The fiddle doesn't appear to do anything

Comment: First, disable all pop-up-blockers(or "allow-this-time"), then we'll see an image(the logo of jsfiddle) centered in the popup window